# JPA/Hibernate Overhead for large dataset

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a scenario at hand, where I need to fetch a large dataset and access it readonly. The dataset consists of multiple tables, so we are talking about 4-5 interconnected tables in the result and a few tables in the query to get to the actual rows needed. Currently this happens through general purpose entities. If I'm not entirely mistaken issueing the queries directly takes <1% of the time Hibernate needs after looking at the statistics.

The queries of hibernate are optimized in the way, that the amount of queries stays small via use of `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`. So the statistics actually say, that there were 28 queries. I actually managed to speed it up by reducing usage of `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` on a comparably small table, so the number of queries only increases a little. Removing `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`, somewhere else, makes it worse (and the query count goes crazy)

I'm not too familiar with hibernate, I feel like hibernate is adding unnecessary overhead by merging entities together, while it's not necessary to merge anything since it's a readonly scenario.

So what I would ask is, if JPA is capable of getting near plain sql.

- Is the JPA overhead expected here or is it a result of bad jpa usage on my side?
- If it is expected, is there a JPA way of preventing the overhead from happening, like telling JPA not to merge resulting entities, that are the same?
- If there is none, what are other usual technologies for this kind of scenario?

I hope I didn't assume too much wrong things, so you can follow this. :)

Comment: maybe explain your usage more - where are you seeing 'merge' happening? If this is a read-only situation, are you maybe wrapped in a transaction and committing it?

Comment: I don't actually see the merge happening, I'm just assuming that it should happen, if I have 1M entities referencing a set of 20 entities and I do subselects instead of additional queries. The transaction might actually be a thing. I don't do any changes, but if I'm not mistaken there is no actual difference in readonly and writing usage. So at this point we are at "Is the JPA overhead expected here or is it a result of bad jpa usage on my side?" Would you expect jpa to work in a readonly case close to plain sql performance complexity wise?

Comment: JPA always 'works', but has an overhead on reads as it takes the raw data and builds objects. How significant this is depends, but is offset largely through caching and different layers of caching of the entities being built. You have to debug to figure out what overhead exactly you are hitting though. Other side of things is when committing a transaction. JPA requires providers to check for updates, so how you've marked your transaction as 'read-only' is an implementation specific thing that could be being done inefficiently and adding overhead too.